# Is it a good practice to have multiple views per module in a flutter project using GetX Pattern?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a flutter project using GetX library.
I try to follow the GetX Pattern ([more about GetX Pattern here](https://github.com/kauemurakami/getx_pattern)).

My question is about code architecture. Is it considered a good practice to have multiple views inside one module?

Currently, I have a Authentication module that contains several views (login_view, register_view, forgot_password_view, etc...), like on the screen below:

[image: folder structure with getx pattern]

I find it more logical that way, but I didn't find any example of people doing the same.

The problem I have with one view per module is that I end up with a lot of modules, and it becomes difficult to navigate the folder tree when your app is getting more complex.

Comment: do you understand?

Answer (score 2):

When your project is too big, it's so tough to handle. It would be good practice if you go with feature driven structure.

```
view
├─ auth_view
│  ├─ auth_view.dart
│  ├─ widget
│  │  ├─ email_validate_view.dart
│  │  ├─ password_validate_view.dart
├─ home_view/
├─ shop_view/
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and make sure that your answer really answers the question op has asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can separate by global widgets and module widgets, having page.dart as main.
I recommend you a project of your own, based on various programming patterns made to meet languages ​​with a reactive paradigm.
https://github.com/kauemurakami/getx_pattern